# Correct way of handling Tornado read_bytes method

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I am working on the python app with a tornado, In which I want to listen data sent by the client continuously.
Here is my code:

```
async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
            try:
                while True:
                    data = stream.read_bytes(1024, callback = self._on_read, partial = True)
                    print(data)
                    stream.write(data)
            except StreamClosedError:
                logger.error("%s disconnected", address)
```

But I am facing following problems:

- when I send data for the first time it invokes _on_read function but for the 2nd time, it does not process that data.
- `stream.write(data)` gives the following error,

> tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(.null_wrapper at 0x7fd3ddf2ce18>, 
>   exception=AssertionError('Already reading',)>)
>               Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in
>   _run_callback
>                   ret = callback()
>                 File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line
>   300, in null_wrapper
>                   return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>                 File "/server.py", line 143, in 
>                   lambda f: f.result())
>                 File "/server.py", line 90, in handle_stream
>                   data = stream.read_bytes(1024, callback = self._on_read, partial = True)
>                 File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 432, in
>   read_bytes
>                   future = self._set_read_callback(callback)
>                 File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 859, in
>   _set_read_callback
>                   assert self._read_callback is None, "Already reading"
>               AssertionError: Already reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to get the data through two incompatible methods, through both the callback and the future. The error is not in stream.write, but when you call stream.read_bytes a second time with a callback.

As [callbacks are deprecated](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream.read_bytes), the best is to use the future. That is, something like this :

```
async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
            try:
                while True:
                    data = await stream.read_bytes(1024, partial = True)
                    print(data)
                    # stream.write(data)
            except StreamClosedError:
                logger.error("%s disconnected", address)
```

Also, the stream.write will write the data back to the same stream. Is it really what you want to do ?

Comment: You try to get the data through two incompatible methods, through both the callback and the future.
As I am new to tornado and python I didn't get you.
Can you please explain?

Comment: Don't use the callback parameter, you will get the data directly with await, as in my example